# JLPT N5 Test 「えきから たいしかんまでの（X）をかいてください。」

Tags: conjugations, jlpt

The question was to select which word would fill in the blank (x) below:

> えきから たいしかんまでの（X）をかいてください。

The options to select as correct answers were:

> １．しゃしん　　２．ちず　　３．てがみ　　４．きっぷ

I thought the answer was 4, with the translation being "Please buy  a ticket from the Station to the Embassy.
However, it seems the answer given in the booklet was 2.
It seems to me that both answers are plausible, is there something in the translation that I'm missing?

Comment: かう→かって https://en.m.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E8%B2%B7%E3%81%86

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out by @broken headphones, I was conjugating the wrong verbs.
I was mistakenly thinking the verb was 'To Buy', when it was in fact 'To Write'.

This means the sentence is actually 'Please write a (X) from the station to the embassy.', for which the only valid answer would be

> 2. ちず

Comment: Well, I don't think a 地図(ちず) is written. (Maybe you should **draw** a map instead of **write** one. This would make it 描いて instead of 書いて)